# mysql: insert right now vs gather many insert statements then insert

Tags: mysql, sql

which one should I use? suppose one insert statement will be produced every second, should I gather 100/1000 insert statements and then do a batch insert at one time? or just insert one when the system produce one?

Comment: Wouldn't this rather depend on your requirements?

Comment: @eggyal for example?

Comment: You need to consider the table you are inserting into as well. How many indexes and foreign keys are there? Also, how volatile is your data? If you collect 1000 statements in memory you could potentially lose 16 minutes of data.

Comment: For example, whether you require them in the database as they're produced; or whether you need to reduce the load on the database from many write operations to a few.

Comment: This is a very broad question because the answer is: it depends on your requirements! From a MySQL performance point of view only, you should do batch inserts, not just one insert at a time. However, you need to consider timeliness ( can I wait 1000 seconds before inserting a record?) and business continuity (what if the system goes down and I loose 999 records) aspects as well. Only **you** can assess these requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You should decide what approach better depending on your conditions.

**[example 1]**

```
INSERT INTO test_table (col1, col2) values (1,"value1"),(2,"value2"), (3,"value3");
```

**[example 2]**

```
INSERT INTO test_table (col1, col2) values (1,"value1");
INSERT INTO test_table (col1, col2) values (2,"value2");
INSERT INTO test_table (col1, col2) values (3,"value3");
```

Inserts like in example 1 will be 10 or more times faster than example 2.
But if one of the operation will be failed, e.g. by UNIQUE KEY, all the transaction will be interrupted so you won't insert all data properly. So one global insert allows to increase performance, several inserts gives more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

As @eggyal has suggested, this depends on your workload:

- What is the size of each row being inserted? If its fairly small then, generally if you are producing one per second, it probably won't matter if you insert per second or accumulate 1000/10000 before committing.
- What kind of durability do you require? If you need to make sure that each insert makes it to disk at the time of request, then one per second or less is what you need paired with highest durability settings of your server. If you are caching the rows somewhere else i.e. Redis, and comfortable with that before batching the insert to MySQL, then it can work for you as well as long as the durability settings on Redis works for you.